# What does src/main/java and src/test/java in a maven project means?

Tags: maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, naming-conventions, coding-style

I'm creating a maven project for selenium automation. What is the use of src/main/java and src/test/java ? What should they include? Where should my Junit test case be kept i.e. either src/main/java or src/test/java ? Please guide me what convention should i follow.. please suggest example too.

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Answer (score 0):

src/main/java is the root directory for your source code. src/test/java/ is the root directory for your test code. So if you had one class called Sample and one test class called SampleTest in package kishan.org your files would be:
src/main/java/org/kishan/Sample.java and src/test/java/org/kishan/SampleTest.java

Maven knows that the tests will be found in the src/test directory and the source code will be found in the src/main directory.